# htaccess rewrite to maintenance page if exists and not IP, else bootstrap

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would I rewrite all requests to `maintenance.php`, if it exists, except images, and except an IP white list.

If `maintenance.php` does not exist it should rewrite to a bootstrap (`index.php`) if the requested file does not exist.

If `maintenance.php` does exist and the IP is in the white list, then it should rewrite to a bootstrap (`index.php`) if the requested file does not exist.

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111$
    RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in reverse.  Rewrite to the bootstrap if the maintenance page doesn't exist or the IP is valid.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.123$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]
```

So, basically it will run index.php IF:

```
(Not a file) 
&& (Not a dir) 
&& (
    (Maintenance Doesn't Exist) 
    || (Remote Addr == 123.123.123.123)
    || (Remote Addr == 111.111.111)
)
```

We could expand this out using propositional logic, but why bother...

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up using

I hope it help any future visitors:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} ^(x\.x\.x\.x|y\.y\.y\.y|z\.z\.z\.z)$ [OR]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !^(x\.x\.x\.x|y\.y\.y\.y|z\.z\.z\.z)$
    RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also @ircmaxell gets the tick because he helped me come to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your IP addresses within brackets in the same `RewriteCond`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.123\.123\.123|111\.111\.111\.111)$
    RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```